# where is Viewer Draw mk3? I cannot find it in the Viz menu

Tags: node-editor, sverchok

I have recently started to learn sverchok on Blender 2.92. Following a tutorial I realised the viewer Draw MK3 node in Viz is not there. Searching for a solution I read somewhere that I have to update Sverchok and I did. However the problem is not solved and I cannot find any other solution. Any ideas? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I am pretty sure that Viewer Draw is the same node just in a newer version. They just renamed it.

UPDATE:

You can use the mesh viewer. It has input sockets vertices, faces and edges.

[image]

Comment: But in the Viewer Draw there is no faces option to connect like in Mk3. or there is a way to make it appear?

Comment: i updated my answer. If this doesn't help, please provide your blend file so that i can see what you are doing. Thank you.

Comment: mk# are iterations of same node. so we move old mk2 to outdated nodes show to user mk3 as only choice. Viewer draw always newest mk# from menu